# 5GHz Wifi suddenly stopped working, but 2.4GHz continues working

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

About two weeks ago my 5 GHz internet suddenly stopped working on my 3 Windows 10 machines (two laptops, one desktop) and also on two Android devices. Prior to that they'd been working for a long time without any issues. However, the 2.4 GHz band continues to work fine.

In one of my Windows 10 machines I tried going into Device Manager -> Network adapters and updating all the drivers, but that didn't change anything.

It isn't because of my location within the house - I've moved the laptops around to various locations and that hasn't fixed anything.

The modem is a Netcomm NF18ACV.

What could cause this to happen? What could be tried to fix it?

Comment: Have you rebooted the router?

Comment: That fixed it! I'll leave the question open since the "What caused this to happen" bit is still unresolved, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably some buffer on the router was full ...